Email DNS Issues after Transfer to AWS Route 53
I recently transferred my domain, asimov.au, from Google Domains to AWS Route 53. As a result, I'm having issues with receiving emails from some senders. My email is through Google Workspace.
In addition, some websites (including StackOverflow) are flagging my email as temporary and not allowing me to sign up.
I am also seeing some confusing and contradictory results on various DNS lookup websites.
The following tools are reporting the correct records:

DNS Checker*
MX Toolbox

The following tools are not showing the correct records:

NS Lookup
Google Toolbox

*DNS checker is showing that the MX records have not propagated to all locations, despite being well over the 48 hour mark.
I've done the following to try to resolve the issue:

Exported the DNS records from Google Domains and imported them into a hosted zone in AWS
Waited 48 hours for propagation
Used Google and Cloudflare's purge cache tools to request a purge for the domains on their servers
Verified the domain in Google Workspace, which successfully found the MX records, and ensured payment is up to date
Ensured settings are correct as per this answer

The domain settings in Route 53 are as follows:
route 53 dashboard
And the zone is configured like so:
zone setup
Note:
I added the apex A record pointing to loopback as a test to see if it's propagating

In case someone else comes across this, I figured out what was happening. It was due to a DNSSEC record that appeared to be imported when the domain was transferred but was not correct. The fix was to delete the DNSSEC key and disable it. Propagation started almost immediately and synced to all major servers in about an hour.
I originally checked for DS records in my Route 53 hosted zone but didn't realise that they don't appear there, they appear under the "registered domains" page, in a tab called DNSSEC Keys.
Note that the issue wasn't because DNSSEC was enabled, it was because of a misconfiguration. The best solution is to generate a valid key and configure DNSSEC correctly rather than disabling it.
